# Thresholding of a grayscale Image in a range

Tags: python, opencv

Does OpenCV `cv.InRange` function work only for RGB images?Can I do thresholding of grayscale image using this function?

I got an error,Following is my code:

```
   import cv2
   image=cv2.imread("disparitySGB.jpg")
   thresh=cv2.inRange(image,190,255);
```

It gives the following error:

> thresh=cv2.inRange(image,190,255);    TypeError: unknown is not a
>   numpy array

I tried fixing it by:

```
  thresh=cv2.inRange(image,numpy.array(190),numpy.array(255));
```

Now there is no error but it produces black image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a gray-valued image which has shape (M, N) in numpy and size MxN with one single channel in OpenCV, then `cv2.inRange` takes scalar bounds:

```
gray = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
gray_filtered = cv2.inRange(gray, 190, 255)
```

But for RGB-images which have shape (M, N, 3) in numpy and size MxN with three channels in OpenCV you need to have the bounds match the "channel size".

```
rgb = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
rgb_filtered = cv2.inRange(gray, (190, 190, 190), (255, 255, 255))
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange), although not very clearly.

Comment: Thank You so much ! It worked :).Yes the documentation is not clear,I read it many time ,still didn't get it .

Answer (score 1):

```
cv2.inRange(src, lowerb, upperb[, dst]) → dst
```

Takes `src` as  array and `lower`and `upper` as `array` or a `scalar`, this means you can use it to Threshold Grayscale images. You just have to use `scalars` for `upper` and `lower`.

Example:

```
myResult = cv2.InRange(myGrayscale, 50, 100)
```

Comment: Thank You! I tried this before but I got an error,so I thought may be it only accept RGB image.

Comment: I have edited the question to include some code.Kindly help me out.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I thought your goal was to use inRange on grayscale and not rgb. But @kigurai posted an excellent answer.

Comment: Actually the image was grayscale ,but it was three channel image.I was not converting it into single channel,(setting flag cv2.CV_BGR2GRAY),and hence was getting black image.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to 'import numpy as np' and your original code should work fine.

Comment: Sorry! but this is not the answer . It does not make difference if you use numpy or as np.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cv2.imread` is reading a RGB image. To read in grayscale it is

```
image = cv2.imread("disparitySGB.jpg", 0)
```